# render a google map into other id

Tags: google-maps, render

have an application with many tabs updated with Ajax. Each tab may contain a different map (actually many Maps, but the problem can be described more easily considering one single map). The problem is that each time I change to another tab, the map I had there seems lost because when I return to that tab later, the map disappears, and I have to ask for it again. The problem reduces to update the corresponding id with the map obtained with “new google.maps.Map(...)”

Simply stated, what I want is to know how can I render  a Google map in some  other  id? I mean something like this:

myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(‘id1’), mapOpt);

renderGoogleMap(myMap, ’id2’)

As an example, I present the code bellow, based on a Google’s Tutorial code, where I added  a new function (renderMap()) that is triggered  after  the rendering of the map  on the 1st ID. What I want to know is how to implement the renderMap funtion so that it renders  the map stored in the gmap variable on the ‘map1’ id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #map {
                width: 360px;
                height: 240px;
                background-color: grey;
            }
            #map1 {
                width: 360px;
                height: 240px;
                background-color: grey;
            }
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="map1"></div>
        <script>
            var gmap;
            function renderMap() {
            // renders the GoogleMap "gmap" on ’map1’ id
            }
            function initMap() {
                gmap = new   google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
                });
            renderMap();
            } 
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=initMap"
                    async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  a new create map

```
 myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('id1'), mapOpt);

 myMap2 =new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('id2'), mapOpt);
```

.

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="map1"></div>
    <script>
        var gmap;
        var gmap1;

        function renderMap(aMapID) {
            return google.maps.Map(aMapID, {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            });
        }
        function initMap() {
            gmap1 = renderMap(document.getElementById('map'));
            gmap2 = renderMap(document.getElementById('map1'));
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=initMap"
                async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem, and is my current implementation. What I want to know is if I can reuse the gmap variable to render it in another id. Your answer suggests is that a map request is tied  to one  and only one ID. What I want to know is how (if it is possible) to render  the gmap  variable into different IDs (1:n). I searched it  with no  success for days. Maybe I am searching the wrong words,  but I don't know which are the correct ones. Am I right to presume the  Google Maps API V3  does not provide   this  functionality?

Comment: The creation (render)  of the map in done inside   a div  and the  cration return an object to refer to the map showed  in the div ..  so you cannot  use the same object  in two div ...  because the map object   is not the image rendered  but a "map object" ..  if you need  you can bind some attribute between the tow maps  (eahc one related to one div) ...  hope is clear ...